# Potentiometer vs Varistor

Tags: components, potentiometer, circuit-design, varistor

What is the main difference between and potentiometer, rheostat and a varistor?  And how do the application of the three in a circuit differ? Or to be more concise, in a variable power supply why would you want to use each one rather than the others, or what benefits would one give over another in a variable power supply circuit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Varistor is a voltage-dependent-resistor. Its resistance depends on the voltage applied to it, and it is a 2-terminal device.
[image] or 
[image]

A Potentiometer is a fixed resistance with a mechanically adjustable wiper which can be moved from one end of the fixed resistance to the other, forming an adjustable voltage divider. It is a 3-terminal device.
[image] or 
[image]

A Rhoestat is not the same thing as a Potentiometer, since a Rheostat is typically considered to be mechanically variable resistor and is a 2-terminal device.
You can use a Potentiometer as a Rheostat by simply ignoring one of its fixed-resistor terminals.
[image] or 
[image]

The application in-circuit of a Varistor vs a Potentiometer is not really comparable as they are completely different devices.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate by referencing in what type of power circuit you would want to use each one and why.

Comment: My layman's understanding is that potentiometers are used in low-power applications - typically to control a signal amplitude.  Conversely, rheostats are used in higher power applications to actually control power, e.g. a light dimmer switch.

Comment: Calling a rheostat a potentiometer is pretty damn common, however.

Comment: @hobbs Probably because a potentiometer with one end disconnected is a rheostat.